# How to use CPack to pack several cmake build results?

Tags: c++, cmake, cpack

As I have to build both static and shared library for x86 and arm platform. So with the same CMakeLists.txt, I have to run it four times with different configuration. I want to use CPack to pack those libraries to one tar file. However, it seems that only the last cmake build results will be included in the tar file.

Is there any idea for this problem?

Here is part of my CMakeLists.txt:

```
install(FILES api_cpp.h api_c.h  DESTINATION api_lib/include)
install(TARGETS lib
ARCHIVE DESTINATION api_lib/${lib_folder}
LIBRARY DESTINATION api_lib/${lib_folder})

INCLUDE(CPack)
SET(CPACK_GENERATOR "TGZ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you use a *single-configuration generator* -- meaning that you can't have more than one particular build configuration in the same build directory. Actually the problem exists even for the *multi-configuration generators* as well (at least for CMake < 3.16).

To make a package one ought to run CMake, which generates build files, then build a project, and finally can make a package (e.g., w/ `make package`). The last action runs CPack, which performs `make install DESTDIR=<some-temporary-dir>`, and then `cpack` just compress the directory into an archive. So, having a build directory with *the only configuration* it's impossible to have an archive with few of them.

To make your need possible you ought to run CMake 4 times doing install into the same location and then pack that directory into a package. It can be done with CMake+CPack, but IMHO easier to do w/ a trivial shell script :)